# sort an array of structs with multiple criteria c#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have an array of structs which needs to be sorted first by st, then by priority and then by id.
this is my struct:

```
 struct File {  
   public int priority, id, st;
 }
```

and this is my array:

```
 File[] Files = new File[10];
```

is there an easy way to do that kind of sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` methods from the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
var result = Files.OrderBy(x => x.st)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.priority)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.id)
                  .ToList(); // Or ToArray()
```

You can also use *Query Syntax* for such Linq query:

```
var result = (from file in Files
             orderby file.st, file.priority, file.id
             select file).ToList(); // Or ToArray()
```

Keep in mind that query expres­sions are trans­lated into their lambda expres­sions before they’re com­piled.

Comment: You also need to add : `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Comment: can I keep the sorted result as an array?

Comment: @user107761 Of course just change `ToList()` to `ToArray()`.